# React DOM not updated after state updated in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

In my React app, I have a parent component with multiple child components. So multiple sections (child components) with fields in each of them.
I have a global state object (Context API) and within this global state, each of the child components have their own state (set via that child section's API call).

I kind of use a Data down Actions Up to only update/set the global state at the parent component and then in the child components, I just consume this state to render the fields.

Below is how individual child components invoke the action via prop to update their piece of the state.

So, I make a call to formatSectionDataForms which kind of merges currentSectionResponse with existingData

Here existingData is my global state at that point of time.

```
let formattedData = formatSectionDataForms(currentSectionResponse, existingData);
props.updateSectionFromChild({
    sectionGroupOrder: formattedData.sectionGroupOrder,
    sectionGroups: {
        ...formattedData.sectionGroups,
        'Section 1': formattedData.sectionGroups['Section 1']
    }
});
```

Now, in each of my child components, I also have a useEffect which sets a local state from this global context object based on myGlobalContextData and then the field is rendered to the UI

```
useEffect(() => {   
    if (myGlobalContextData&& myGlobalContextData.sectionGroups['Child Section 1'] && myGlobalContextData.sectionGroups['Child Section 1'].sections 
        && myGlobalContextData.sectionGroups['Child Section 1'].sections['child-section-1'].fields 
        && myGlobalContextData.sectionGroups['Child Section 1'].sections['child-section-1'].fields.length > 0) {
            data = myGlobalContextData;
            if (clientProfileFormData && clientProfileFormData.sectionGroups['Current Section'] && clientProfileFormData.sectionGroups['Current Section'].sections 
                    && clientProfileFormData.sectionGroups['Current Section'].sections['current-section-2'].fields 
                    && clientProfileFormData.sectionGroups['Current Section'].sections['current-section-2'].fields.length === 0) {
                getCurrentSectionData();
            }

            const section = myGlobalContextData?.sectionGroups[sectionGroupName].sections[sectionName];     

            setMyLoacalState({
                ...myLocalState,
                myField: section.fields.find(field => field.id == 'my-field')
            });
    }        
},[myGlobalContextData]);
```

Now, the issue is in certain cases, I observe that I do not get to see the proper existingData and even though that section's state is updated in the useEffect, the same values is not reflected on the UI.

How can I ensure that the DOM gets updated after I set the local state from the global context object ?